# Can I attack two rsa encryption knowing they have different encrypted messages and different modulus, yet a common exponent?

Tags: encryption, rsa, public-key-encryption

So yeah, different modulus(n), same exponent(e), different encrypted messages(C). Can I do anything with that to find the original messages(M) ? Thank you !

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is isn't a programming question.

Comment: Most rsa uses the public exponent 65537, so such an attack would render RSA completely broken.

Answer (score 1):

Sure. You can factor the modulus, altho for real world RSA keys, that's not gonna be very practical.

More seriously, 99% of all RSA keys [use 65537 as the exponent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/65537_(number)). If a common public exponent were a weakness 99% of all RSA applications would be vulnerable.